# Error "cannot do complex assignments in base namespace" comes up when trying to knit

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio

Knitting my `.Rmd` document chokes and gives me an error. My `.Rprofile` has a few things in it that I need regularly on startup and the first bit that seems to be causing problems is one that converts the type for a commonly used variable. This is the full error message:

> Error in e$e_pop_num <- as.numeric(e$e_pop_num) : 
>         cannot do complex assignments in base namespace
>       Execution halted
>
> knitr terminated with status 1

If I comment out all these manipulations in my `.Rprofile` or wrap them into a function (which I can't get to work either), then the knitting works fine.

I don't pretend to totally understand namespaces or environments, but I get that here lies the problem. So either:

- I move this code out of my `.Rprofile`. In which case, my question is, where is the best place to put this kind of 'use every time' code?, or
- How can I configure `Rstudio` or my `.Rmd` script so it can evaluate my `.Rprofile` without getting stuck?

Session info:
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

Rstudio Version 0.98.490

Here is the contents of my .Rprofile simplified to make it reproducible.

```
e <- data.frame(x=1:5, e_pop_num=6:10)

# set e_pop_num to numeric to avoid integer overflow error
e$e_pop_num <- as.numeric(e$e_pop_num)
```

Comment: Could you show your .Rprofile ? Wrapping your code in a function should work.

Comment: Is wrapping in a function the best way to do this sort of thing? Where I got stuck was getting the objects in the function in my .Rprofile into the global environment.

Comment: Without further details of your .Rprofile, it is impossible to guess what is going on here. In particular, what is `e`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if I reduced my .Rprofile to only that line I would still get the error, but I will have to try it out. `e` is only a data.frame.

Comment: @Yihui Just to follow-up, I tried it again with the above reduced version of my .Rprofile and got the same error.

Comment: @KarlForner .Rprofile now included.

Comment: Still not reproducible under R 3.0.2.

Comment: @Yihui Okay I've updated my R, Rstudio and all packages and am still getting the error on my Windows 7 PC. I'll call this unsolvable and stick with my workaround function. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into a similar issue myself. However, I only got this issue for an `Rprofile.site`, not an `.Rprofile`.

I found a workaround by creating a hidden environment, assigning objects to it using `local` and then attaching it.

```
# Create hidden environment
.env = new.env()

# Assign object in hidden environment
local({
  e <- data.frame(x = 1:5, e_pop_num = 6:10)
  e$e_pop_num <- as.numeric(e$e_pop_num)
}, envir = .env)

# Attach hidden environment
attach(.env)
```

As an `.Rprofile` instead of an `Rprofile.site`, also the following works for me:

```
# Create hidden environment
.env = new.env()

# Assign object in hidden environment
.env$e <- data.frame(x = 1:5, e_pop_num = 6:10)
.env$e$e_pop_num <- as.numeric(.env$e$e_pop_num)

# Attach hidden environment
attach(.env)
```

**UPDATE**

For R version >= 4.1.0 the above solution for `Rprofile.site` will cause an error:

```
Error: cannot add binding of '.env' to the base environment
```

From the [R news](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html) for version 4.1.0 this seems to be a new design choice to protect the base environment:
"The base environment and its namespace are now locked (so one can no longer add bindings to these or remove from these)".

The workaround is to create the environment within `local()`:

```
# Assign object in hidden environment
local({
  # Create hidden environment
  .env = new.env()
  
  # Create object
  e <- data.frame(x = 1:5, e_pop_num = 6:10)
  e$e_pop_num <- as.numeric(e$e_pop_num)
  
  # Assign to environment
  assign("e", e, envir = .env)
  
  # Attach hidden environment
  attach(.env)
})
```

Comment: Thank you, Roel. I'll have to give that a try. Glad it worked for you!

Comment: This no longer seems to work in `Rprofile.site` after updating to R 4.1.0. It now errors: `Error: cannot add binding of '.env' to the base environment`.


Reason seems to be by design choice of R core developers. Source: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html

"The base environment and its namespace are now locked (so one can no longer add bindings to these or remove from these)."

Haven't found a new workaround yet for `Rprofile.site`. Still works in `.Rprofile`.

Comment: Added an update for R version 4.1.0 in the solution above.

Answer (score 1):

wrap your assignments in an if block.

```
if(interactive()){
   #assignments
}
```

From briefly reading ?Startup if you are not in an interactive session .RProfile is executed in the base environment while in interactive sessions assignment is to the user global environment.  Knitr when using RStudio starts a new non-interactive R process when it runs, which is why you are getting the error I suspect.

Comment: Thanks @Jim. That works for knitting, but now when I open R (or Rstudio) I get the error.

Comment: I added your lines to my .Rprofile, and I have no problem to run rstudio and to knit Rmd documents. I use R-3.0.1 on linux with Rstudio 0.98.456

Comment: @Tom is there a solution for the windows ? I  get the same error ? `.Rprofile_env <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
 .Rprofile_env$installpak <- pak::pkg_install
  attach(.Rprofile_env)`

Comment: @user5249203 I haven't found one, but I also stopped looking. Now I wrap most everything in my .Rprofile in a function called `runprofile()` and then only run it when I need it. It's kind of made .Rprofile useless, but maybe I was depending too much on it anyway.

Comment: Hi tom, Here is what I did for creating a new install function. Instead `$` to access `[[` list access helped to create a new global function install. May be you would like to try this. It worked fine after restarting the R session  ` .__Rprofile_env__. <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
    .__Rprofile_env__.[["install"]] <- pak::pkg_install
    attach(.__Rprofile_env__.)`